# Compare date times chosen with date and time picker in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So i have a multi-page form that uses two "Date and time Picker" controls named StartDate and EndDate. I want to ensure that the user does not enter the StartDate later than the EndDate. I have the following questions.  Is the StartDate.value initially "" or is it null? Is what's returned by StartDate a string or a date? Here is what I have so far.

As a side remark I am also somewhat confused by this line of code even after reading the documentation.

emptyRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

```
Private Sub StartDate_Change()
Dim emptyRow As Long
'Submits the date in the first empty row immediately since the form does not retain datepicker data after the page changes.
If (EndDate.Value) <> "" And CDate(StartDate.Value) >= CDate(EndDate.Value) Then
MsgBox ("Please enter a valid date")
MultiPage1.Value = 4


Else
Sheet1.Activate
emptyRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
Cells(emptyRow, 18).Value = StartDate.Value

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `CountA` counts non blank cells. So that line is finding all non blanks in column A and adding 1 to get the last empty row. This only works if there are no gaps in the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTimePickers` return `Dates`.

If you want to test that the EndDate is greater than StartDate, then code such as the following should do the trick:

`(StartDate.Value < EndDate.Value)`